# Buttons Don't Initially Draw

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt

I'm having an issue with my applet where the buttons do not draw until you mouse over them. They stay after that, but once you click one, they go away again. Here is my code:

```
    checkPanel = new JPanel();

    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, 7 ) );

    openAdvancedSettings = new JButton( "Advanced Settings" );
    openAdvancedSettings.addActionListener( this );

    checkPanel = new JPanel();
    checkvolt = new Checkbox( "Voltage", true );
    checkv = new Checkbox( "v gate", false );
    checkw = new Checkbox( "w gate", false );
    checks = new Checkbox( "s gate", false );

    checkvolt.addItemListener( this );
    checkv.addItemListener( this );
    checkw.addItemListener( this );
    checks.addItemListener( this );

    checkPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout( 20, 8 ) );
    checkPanel.add( butp );
    checkPanel.add( prompt0 );
    checkPanel.add( checkvolt );
    checkPanel.add( prompt1 );

    butt = new JButton( "Start" );
    butt.addActionListener( this );
    buttonPanel.add( butt );

    setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    add( checkPanel, BorderLayout.EAST );
    add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH );
    add( openAdvancedSettings, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
```

The first 2 adds are JPanels, and the last one is a JButton. Most of the buttons (all but the last one) are in those 2 panels.

I have also come to the conclusion that the method repaint() is causing this to happen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume that the code you have posted here is inside the init() method. Isn't that?

Comment: See, [How to Make Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html) for a simple example of what the init() method of your JApplet should look like to create and add components to the applet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming in the absence of a good [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), that you must have failed to put your code, that is responsible for creating and displaying your GUI, for attaining [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), inside SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...); 
Secondly, you can try calling revalidate() method, on your panel, before calling repaint(). That might can solve the problem for the time being.

Hope that might help in some way.
Regards

Comment: Sorry if I'm making it harder then it needs to be, but the code I'm working with isn't mine. It is also 1800 lines long, so distilling it is not easy. I realized what was wrong, and am attempting to fix it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

- Don't mix Swing (e.g. `JPanel`) & AWT (e.g. `CheckBox`) components.  Comment out any AWT import(s) and check that only layouts are missing.
- Ensure that `validate()` is called after all components are added.
- And as Gagandeep Bali advised:-  Construct the GUI on the EDT, and post an SSCCE if you cannot get it sorted.

Comment: +1 for pointing  out AWT Components along with Swing, I forgot to mention that. :-)  Regards

Comment: Glad to answer on the same page as you. I just remembered you are the real person who wrote that SSCCE Document, the link for which I gave in my answer. :-)  Regards

Comment: @GagandeepBali  Ditto.  I liked your answer but could not resist mentioning a few things of my own.  As to the Swing/AWT mix, I was lucky to catch it!  I usually only look closely at code once it is compiled and sitting in my editor.  ;)